# Scope of variables mechanism in c

Tags: c

How the mechanisms of variable's scope work (local, static and global)?

I don't understand this output:

```
void foo1(int *z)
{
  z = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *z = 3;
}

void foo2(int *t)
{
  *t = 3;
}

void main()
{
  int y = 1;
  int x = 2;
  foo1(&y);
  foo2(&x);
  printf("%d %d", y, x);
}
```

output:    `1 3`

Comment: Why are you even using `malloc`?

Comment: The passed `z` is overwritten with `(int *)malloc(sizeof(int))`. It does not point to `y` anymore.

Comment: Whenever you pass in a variable to a function, you pass **a copy of it**. So, when, `foo1` receives the pointer to `y`, it overwrites it in the first statement, making the second statement have no effect on main's `y`.

Comment: @soon - so why is the output like this?

Comment: What does this question have to do with scope?

Answer (score 0):

```
void foo1(int *z)
{
  z = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *z = 3;
}
```

I am not sure why you are using `malloc`, but `*z` ends up pointing to the memory address of the memory you just assigned with the malloc. So overriding the original pointer means the change isn't reflected in the original `main()` method.

A bit more clear:
You have a pointer `* z` that is pointing to the `y` from `main()`. When you use `malloc` it returns a pointer, so when you assign that to `z`, it is now pointing to a *different* block of memory that has nothing to do with the `y` from `main()`. You then assign this new block of memory the value of `3`. Hence the original `y` is unchanged.

Comment: The `malloc` is part of the question. I don't understand your last sentence. Please look at the output.

Comment: @Ronen333 You have a pointer `* z` that is pointing to the `y` from `main()`. When you use `malloc` it returns a pointer, so when you assign that to `z`, it is now pointing to a *different* block of memory that has nothing to do with the `y` from `main()`. You then assign this new block of memory the value of 3. Hence the original `y` is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in `main`, `int y = 1;` creates a local object named `y` and initializes it to 1.

Then `int x = 2;` creates a local object named `x` and initializes it to 2.

Then `foo1(&y);` calls `foo1` while passing it the address of `y`.

In `foo1(int *z)`, the parameter `z` is effectively an object local to the function `foo1`. As `foo1` starts, `z` contains the address of `y`.

Then `z = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));` allocates memory and assigns the address of that memory to `z`. This changes `z`, so `z` no longer contains the address of `y`.

Then `*z = 3;` puts 3 in the place where `z` points, which is now the allocated memory. So the contents of the allocated memory change. `y` does not change because `z` no longer points to `y`, since `z = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));` changed `z`.

Then `foo1` returns and main calls `foo2(&x);`, which calls `foo2` while passing it the address of `x`.

In `foo2(int *t)`, the parameter `t` is effectively an object local to the function `foo2`. As `foo2` starts, `t` contains the address of `x`.

Then `*t = 3;` puts 3 in the place where `t` points. Since `t` points to `x`, this changes the contents of `x`, so now `x` contains 3.

Then `foo2` returns.

Back inside `main`, `printf("%d %d", y, x);` prints the contents of `y` and `x`. Since `y` did not change, it is still 1. Since `x` did change, it is now 3.